# Php -> Node.js transport/bridge

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, socket.io, dnode

Tell me, please, how to organize a correct transport data from PHP to Node.js?

I tried to use the library [dNode](https://github.com/substack/dnode), but it does not work in conjunction with [socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/).

**Example:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var server = dnode({
        setMeta: function(data, callback) {
            // not working
        }
    });
    server.listen(dPort);
});
```

Advise the alternative?

Comment: This is a good question, and I see what you're saying, but it may just be that there are few people with extensive knowledge of node.js, socket.io and DNode.

Answer (score 4):

To send data from PHP to NodeJS can use the following:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/img.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8082/test'); /* Nodejs */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

In app.js

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("name: " + req.body.name);
...
```

I hope that is helpful.